# Android Leaks while testing in Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Tags: android, android-emulator

i am testing leaks in my first android App..i have exp to in Iphone development iam struggling to detect leaks with memory Analyzer tool in Eclipse these are the issues in App

```
2,371 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 807,856 (31.82%) bytes. 
 class android.text.Html$HtmlParser @ 0x40104b90 - 126,632 (4.99%) bytes. 
class org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services @ 0x400afe18 - 47,056 (1.85%) bytes. 
class com.android.internal.R$styleable @ 0x400735c8 - 38,048 (1.50%) bytes. 
class android.R$styleable @ 0x40051910 - 37,640 (1.48%) bytes. 
class libcore.icu.TimeZones$CachedTimeZones @ 0x404a7480 - 37,624 (1.48%) bytes. 
class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40064e50 - 34,528 (1.36%) bytes. 
class android.text.AutoText @ 0x40107880 - 31,656 (1.25%) bytes.
```

And..Second One Is.

```
    6,669 instances of "java.lang.String", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 15,152  (16.35%) bytes.
```

can any one explain or any suggestions regarding where there problems coming from

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Memory Analyzer just shows the objects with the biggest retained size as leaks. That doesn't mean thos are actually leaks. If you run a test that ensures that the leaked memory increases, it's very likely that you find it in MAT's "leak list". 
Check also http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/search/label/memory for some MAT tips

Answer (score 0):

You have not demonstrated that there is a problem. Everything there seems fairly normal.